# Ошибка добавление записи в таблицу через библиотеку asyncpg

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql, база-данных, postgresql

Есть корутина, добавляющая в таблицу `teachers`, в которую входит только поле `user_id`, запись:

```
async def add_new_teacher(self, user_id :int):
    command = "INSERT INTO teachers(user_id) VALUES ($1) RETURNING id"
    args: tuple = (user_id)
    record_id = await self.pool.fetchval(command, *args)
    return record_id
```

Когда данный код отрабатывает, он выбрасывает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/anton/dev/Bots/EnglishGitBot/dbheandler.py", line 49, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(data_base.add_new_teacher(1)))  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()   File "/home/anton/dev/Bots/EnglishGitBot/dbheandler.py", line 27, in add_new_teacher
    record_id = await self.pool.fetchval(command, *args) TypeError: fetchval() argument after * must be an iterable, not int
```

Почему данный код не работает?

Есть похожая функция, написанная по тому же шаблону и она работает без ошибок. Код работающей функции:

```
async def add_new_user(self, chat_id: int, username: str, full_name: str):
    command = "INSERT INTO users(chat_id, username, full_name) VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING id"
    args :tuple = (chat_id, username, full_name)
    record_id = await self.pool.fetchval(command, *args)
    return record_id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас классическая ошибка:

```
args: tuple = (user_id)
```

Здесь вы создали **скалярную** переменную `args`, а не кортеж.

Пример:

```
In [1]: user_id = 123

In [2]: args: tuple = (user_id)

In [3]: type(args)
Out[3]: int       #  <-------------- NOTE!!!
```

Для того чтобы создать кортеж, состоящий из единственного элемента, добавьте запятую после элемента:

```
In [5]: args: tuple = (user_id, )
#  NOTE: -------------------> ^

In [6]: type(args)
Out[6]: tuple  # <--------- NOTE!!!
```

---

PS запятую нужно добавлять только в том случае, когда создаем кортеж из **одного** элемента:

```
In [7]: args: tuple = (user_id, "a string")

In [8]: type(args)
Out[8]: tuple
```